# Recursive Ruby merge sort

Tags: ruby, array, sorting, mergesort

I have implemented a merge sort in Ruby. (Yes, I know, there's Array#sort) I would like to get feedback on code quality and optimization.

```
def merge(a, b)
  result = []

  while !a.empty? && !b.empty?
    if a[0] <= b[0]
      result << a.shift
    else
      result << b.shift
    end
  end

  result += a += b

  return result
end

def merge_sort(m)
  if m.length <= 1
    return m
  end

  left, right = [], []
  m.each_with_index do |x, i|
    if i < m.length / 2
      left << x
    else
      right << x
    end
  end
  left = merge_sort(left)
  right = merge_sort(right)

  return merge(left, right)
end

input = [*1..100].shuffle

p input

p merge_sort input
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define `left` and `right` in `merge_sort` this way:

```
n = m.length
if n <= 1
  return m
end

left = merge_sort(m[0 ... n/2])
right = merge_sort(m[n/2 .. -1])
```

Depending on your Ruby version, `Array#shift` can be [`O(n)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353026/what-is-the-run-time-of-shift-unshift-in-a-ruby-array). You could keep 2 indices for `a` and `b`:

```
def merge(a, b)
  result = []
  i, j = 0, 0
  na, nb = a.size, b.size

  while i < na && j < nb do
    if a[i] <= b[j]
      result << a[i]
      i += 1
    else
      result << b[j]
      j += 1
    end
  end

  return result + a[i..-1] + b[j..-1]
end
```

With those changes, the code becomes twice as fast with `input = [*1..100000].shuffle`.